# Repeatedly running a function in r till an error is not produced.

Tags: r, error-handling, automation

I apologize that I can not tell you what these functions are form the start.

I have a function `CheckOutCell`. It takes one argument and that is the number `764`. So every time I run the function it looks like this in it's entirety: `CheckOutCell(764)`.

Now many times the function will give me an error:

```
Error in checkInCell(764) : 
The function is currently locked;  try again in a minute.
```

Which is a custom error message and the details are not important to this question.

Now this function could be locked from anywhere from 30 seconds to an hour. I want to be able to automatically run `CheckOutCell(764)` till it goes through, **and then stop running it**. That is, run it till I do not get an error, then stop.

I think a start would be using

```
while(capture.output(checkInCell(764)) == "Error in checkInCell(764) : 
The function is currently locked;  try again in a minute."){
do something}
```

However this just produces

```
Error in checkInCell(764) : 
The function is currently locked;  try again in a minute.
```

because the function is still locked, so no output can be captured.

How would I test for `while(error = T)`

Assume the source code of the function cannot be modified.

Even `is.error(CheckInCell(764))` will just produce the same error message

Comment: Did you try tryCatch yet ?

Comment: I have, I am not sure where to go with it, If I answer my own question using 'tryCatch' I will post it

Comment: try `stopifnot` or `stop` inside if else block. If you are using `stop`, make sure to have call. = FALSE and pass an appropriate error message

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that this code works in a way

```
wrapcheck <- function(x){
repeatCheck =tryCatch(checkOutCell(764), 
                  error = function(cond)"skip")

SudoCheck = ifelse(repeatCheck=="skip",repeatCheck, checkOutCell(764))

while(SudoCheck == "skip"){
repeatCheck
}
}
```

wrapcheck(764)
Basically this checks for an error and then keeps running the function till the error is not produced. In fact I am fairly confident that this would work with any funciton you wanted to put in place of `CheckOutCell`.

The main problem is that when the function is locked, that it not really an error, it is **locked**. Therefore this above block will not work. This above block will work when errors other than a lock are produced.